# Delphi tfilestream.readbuffer fails to read string value from file

Tags: string, delphi, vcl, tfilestream

I am reading and writing data from a file using a filestream but am having a problem reading strings from my file.

In a test VCL form program I have written:

```
procedure tform1.ReadfromFile4;
  var
  fs: TFileStream;
  arrayString: Array of String;
  i, Len1 : Cardinal;
//  s : string;
begin
  fs := TFileStream.Create('C:\Users\Joe\Documents\Delphi\Streamtest.tst',
                 fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  Memo1.lines.clear;

  try
    fs.ReadBuffer(Len1, SizeOf(Len1));
    SetLength(arrayString, Len1);
    FOR i := 0 to Len1-1 do begin
      fs.ReadBuffer(Len1, SizeOf(Len1));
      SetLength(arrayString[i], Len1);
      Fs.ReadBuffer(arrayString[i], Len1);
      memo1.lines.add (arrayString[i]);
    end;
  finally
    fs.free;
  end;
end;

procedure tform1.WriteToFile4;
var
  fs: TFileStream;
  arrayString: Array of String;
  Len1, c, i: Cardinal;
begin
  Memo1.lines.clear;
  SetLength(arrayString, 4);
  arrayString[0] := 'First string in this Array';
  arrayString[1] := 'the Second Array string';
  arrayString[2] := 'String number three of this Array';
  arrayString[3] := 'this is the fourth String';
  fs := TFileStream.Create('C:\Users\Joe\Documents\Delphi\Streamtest.tst',
                 fmCreate or fmOpenWrite or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    c := Length(arrayString);
    Fs.WriteBuffer(c, SizeOf(c));
    for i := 0 to c-1 do begin
      Len1 := Length(arrayString[i]);
      fs.WriteBuffer(Len1, SizeOf(Len1));
      if Len1 > 0 then begin
        fs.WriteBuffer(arrayString[i], Len1);

      end;
    end;
  finally
    fs.free;
  end;

end;
```

The Save button action enters the four strings correctly, but the Load button (readFromFile4) fails to load the strings from the file.  Using the Watch list, I find that the string lengths are set correctly for each string, but the data accessed is not the correct string values.  I believe I am faithfully following the instructions on the website : http://www.angelfire.com/hi5/delphizeus/customfiles.html][1](http://www.angelfire.com/hi5/delphizeus/customfiles.html) in the section titled

> Writing and Reading Dynamic Arrays of Non-Fixed Size Variables

Can anyone shed light on why this does not read the strings from the file correctly?

Comment: Use `FS.WriteBuffer(Pointer(ArrayString[i])^, Len1 * SizeOf(Char));` for writing and `FS.ReadBuffer(Pointer(ArrayString[i])^, Len1 * SizeOf(Char));` for reading. Or simply use `TStreamReader` and `TStreamWriter`.

Comment: Check `TStringList` class it may be more appropriate for your use case.

Comment: @EugeneK  In the actual application the strings are mixed with other data types in a record of which several fields are strings.  When I had problems with the strings i that application I wrote this sample to test for a solution.  A need a broader apporach than what a stringlist offers.

Comment: All of the UI code is irrelevant here. See [mcve], and distill it down to something that does not involve a user interface, which has nothing to do with the question asked. There's no reason for a mention of a form or a button click here.

Comment: You are saving the address of the string content, not the content. Same alwhen reading. With incorrect length. Make the changes that @Victoria describe.

Comment: "_The Save button action appears to enter the four strings correctly_" What do you mean ***appears***? Open the file in your favourite `Notepad.exe` and ***know for certain***! If you're saving correctly, then that code is irrelevant to your question. If not, get that working first!! It should be blatantly obvious that you cannot "successfully" read from a file that is not correctly written in the first place. **TIP**: _You really need to learn to approach things more systematically to program efficiently._